# Counting the occurrence of objects in an ArrayList, using either Collections or my functions

Tags: java, object, collections, arraylist, find-occurrences

I have an ArrayList of FlowerClass objects. Each of these FlowerClass objects has a name. I want to go through the ArrayList and count them. I want to display the amount of each. So if I have three FlowerClass objects named Rose, two named Daffodil, and one named Tulip...I want to display the following:

- Found 3 Rose
- Found 3 Daffodil
- Found 3 Tulip

So far, I've gotten it to count correctly using two functions I made. The problem is that I iterate through the entire ArrayList...so it'll show me the results more than once. For example, if the user adds 3 Roses and 2 Daffodils...The output is like this:

- Found 3 Roses
- Found 3 Roses
- Found 3 Roses
- Found 2 Daffodils
- Found 2 Daffodils

I know why the code does this but I don't know how to erase repeats of output. I also don't know how to implement Collections correctly. I've used Collections on an ArrayList of strings before...and it works. But this time I'd be using Collections on an ArrayList of Objects, and I want to check for the frequency of each specific name. Here is the main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MainClass {

    static ArrayList<FlowerClass> flowerPack = new ArrayList<FlowerClass>();


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){
            System.out.println("1. Add flower to flowerpack.");
            System.out.println("2. Remove flower from the flowerpack.");
            System.out.println("3. Search for a flower in the flowerpack."); 
            System.out.println("4. Display the flowers in the flowerpack.");
            System.out.println("5. Exit the program.");

            int userChoice = input.nextInt();

            switch(userChoice){
            case 1:
                addFlower();
                break;
            case 2:
                searchFlower();
                break;
            case 3:
                displayFlowers();
                break;
            case 4:
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void addFlower(){
        if (FlowerClass.numberFlowers() == 25){
            System.out.println("There are 25 flowers in the flowerpack. Remove at least one in order to add more.");
            return;
        }
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the flower's name?");
        String desiredName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the flower's color?");
        String desiredColor = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many thorns does it have?");
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int desiredThorns = input2.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What does it smell like?");
        String desiredSmell = input.nextLine();
        flowerPack.add(new FlowerClass(desiredName, desiredColor, desiredThorns, desiredSmell));
    }

    public static void searchFlower(){
        System.out.println("Enter the flower you want to search for.");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userChoice = input.nextLine();
        int occurrences  = 0;

        for (FlowerClass flower: flowerPack){
            String name = flower.getName();
            if (userChoice.equals(name)){
                occurrences++;
            }

            else if(occurrences == 0){
                System.out.println("Match not found.");
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Found " + occurrences + " " + userChoice);
    }

    public static void searchFlower(String desiredFlower){
        int occurrences = 0;

        String userChoice = desiredFlower;
        for (FlowerClass flower: flowerPack){
            String name = flower.getName();
            if (userChoice.equals(name)){
            occurrences++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Found " + occurrences + " " + userChoice);
    }

    public static void displayFlowers(){
        int repeats = 0;

        /*for (FlowerClass flower: flowerPack){
            System.out.println(flower.getName());
        }
        System.out.println("Number of flowers in pack: " + FlowerClass.numberFlowers());*/

            //int occurrences = Collections.frequency(flowerPack, name);
            //System.out.println(name + ": " + occurrences);
        for (FlowerClass flower: flowerPack){
            String name = flower.getName();
            searchFlower(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the FlowerClass:

```
public class FlowerClass {

    public static int numberOfFlowers = 0;
    public String flowerName = null;
    public String flowerColor = null;
    public int numberThorns = 0;
    public String flowerSmell = null;

    FlowerClass(){

    }

    FlowerClass(String desiredName, String desiredColor, int desiredThorns, String desiredSmell){
        flowerName = desiredName;
            flowerColor = desiredColor;
        numberThorns = desiredThorns;
        flowerSmell = desiredSmell;
        numberOfFlowers++;
    }

    public void setName(String desiredName){
        flowerName = desiredName;

    }

    public String getName(){
        return flowerName;
    }

    public static int numberFlowers(){
        return numberOfFlowers;
    }
}
```

If you look at my last function in the main class, you'll see that I commented out the way I was attempting to implement Collections.frequency. I also tried making a multidimensional array of Strings and storing the names of the flowers and also the number of flowers in the arrays. This was counting everything correctly but I wasn't sure how to display the names alongside the counts. It was getting very messy so I abandoned that attempt for now in favor of trying these other two options. If I can find a way to erase repeated lines of output (or if I can find a way to get Collections to work) then I won't need to tinker with the multidimensional array.

Any tips would be very much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: use iterator to iterate thoug the arraylist  Iterator itr = al.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting code, but it doesn't work the way I would do it.

In this current case as you've done it, you would need to keep track of the flower names you have already encountered:

```
public static void displayFlowers(){
    //int repeats = 0;
    List<String> displayedFlowerTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (FlowerClass flower: flowerPack){
        String name = flower.getName();
        if(!displayedFlowerTypes.contains(name))
        {
            displayedFlowerTypes.add(name);
            searchFlower(name);
        }
    }
}
```

What I would rather do is maintain a Map that keeps track of the counts of the flower types, and just obtain the numbers for the types from that:

```
public class MainClass {

static List<FlowerClass> flowerPack = new ArrayList<FlowerClass>();
static Map<String, Integer> flowerCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public static void addFlower() {
    if (FlowerClass.numberFlowers() == 25) {
        System.out.println("There are 25 flowers in the flowerpack. Remove at least one in order to add more.");
        return;
    }
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the flower's name?");
    String desiredName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the flower's color?");
    String desiredColor = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How many thorns does it have?");
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int desiredThorns = input2.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What does it smell like?");
    String desiredSmell = input.nextLine();
    flowerPack.add(new FlowerClass(desiredName, desiredColor, desiredThorns, desiredSmell));
    if(!flowerCount.containsKey(desiredName))
    {
        flowerCount.put(desiredName, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        int currentCount = flowerCount.get(desiredName);
        flowerCount.put(desiredName, currentCount+1));
    }
}
```

That way, you could just display the flowers as the following:

```
    public static void displayFlowers() {
        for (String name : flowerCount.keySet()) {
            //searchFlower(name);
            System.out.println("Found " + flowerCount.get(name) + " " + name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I'm not at the point where I'm prepared to use a map. I'm practicing for a midterm project (this is not the midterm project) and I believe we're allowed to use arrays and arraylists for it, so I'm trying to prepare for that. 

I really love the new ArrayList you wrote, though. That's exactly what I need and I can tell that it works already. Perfect answer. I liked the other guy's answer too but this doesn't require another class and it's using ArrayLists which I've already been practicing. Gonna try to implement this.

Comment: I was able to implement it successfully. I love it. I don't have to sort anything, I can remove and add more flowers without any problems so far. It's really great. Thanks for your help.

I'll look into the Map solution as well. Is either solution significantly better in terms of speed? I don't need to worry about speed but I am curious if a Map is faster than an ArrayList when searching for something specific.

Comment: I'm glad it worked as you intended! :) I like the sorting solution because it makes sense, but it's not something I'd want to write down on paper in a midterm test when "errorlessness" and speed of intuitive solutions are a must. The key difference between my two approach is that for the display of all types, the List version needs to iterate through the entire List as many times as there are flower types to get the count which is O(N); but the Map already stores the information in the value to the given key and therefore can be done with a single operation with O(1) rather than list iteration

Comment: So technically if you had many flowers in the List, then the List approach would be significantly slower than the Map solution (to get the number of flowers of each type). But with 25 flowers, the difference isn't really that spectacular.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your Flower(s) in a `Set`. But the easiest solution I can think of is to sort your flowers. So first, implement a [`Comparator<FlowerClass>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
public static class FlowerComparator implements Comparator<FlowerClass> {
  @Override
  public int compare(FlowerClass o1, FlowerClass o2) {
    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
  }
}
```

Then you can sort with [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

```
FlowerComparator flowerComparator = new FlowerComparator();
Collections.sort(flowerPack, flowerComparator);
```

And then your `for` loop needs to be something like this (to stop searching for the same flower),

```
String lastName = null;
for (int i = 0; i < flowerPack.size(); i++){
  FlowerClass flower = flowerPack.get(i);
  String name = flower.getName();
  if (lastName == null || !lastName.equals(name)) {
    lastName = name;
    searchFlower(name); // or return the number found, and then add that count to i.
  }
 }
```

Comment: Perfect. Do you have a preferred resource for Comparators? I'd like to read more about them. Your solution works perfectly. I made a new class called FlowerComparator. It didn't let me leave it as static though. Had to erase static. So the header is:

public class FlowerComparator implements Comparator<FlowerClass